# How to make a git command read settings from .gitconfig file?

Tags: git-config, git

I have figured out how to make my own git command , but I want to be able to allow user saved settings required by my git command into git ~/.gitconfig file and later my git command read from the config file instead of having user to input each time the git command is executed.

Is there a simple way to read `~/.gitconfig` file or do I have to parse read the content ?

Comment: what does this question have to do with python? Are you coding ? Show us your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `git config --global`. It is purpose-built for reading and writing settings to your `.gitconfig`.